# How to fix "The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C8CAB6595FDFF622 Ubuntu Debug Symbol Archive Automatic Signing Key (2016)" on 20.04 LTS

Tags: apt, 20.04, keyrings

## How to fix following problem?

```
# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com focal InRelease                                                                                               
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                
Hit:4 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                             
Hit:5 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                   
Ign:6 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com focal-updates InRelease                                           
Ign:7 https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb focal InRelease        
Hit:8 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease   
Get:9 https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb focal Release [1838 B]
Ign:10 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com focal-proposed InRelease                      
Hit:11 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:12 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com focal Release  
Hit:13 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com focal-proposed Release
Get:14 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com focal-updates Release [40.5 kB]
Get:15 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com focal-updates Release.gpg [819 B]
Err:17 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com focal Release.gpg
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C8CAB6595FDFF622 Ubuntu Debug Symbol Archive Automatic Signing Key (2016) <ubuntu-archive@lists.ubuntu.com>
Err:18 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com focal-proposed Release.gpg
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C8CAB6595FDFF622 Ubuntu Debug Symbol Archive Automatic Signing Key (2016) <ubuntu-archive@lists.ubuntu.com>
Err:15 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com focal-updates Release.gpg
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C8CAB6595FDFF622 Ubuntu Debug Symbol Archive Automatic Signing Key (2016) <ubuntu-archive@lists.ubuntu.com>
Fetched 43.1 kB in 2s (27.1 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

(Please ignore the non-Ubuntu repositories above.  They are not part of the problem.)

### Notes

- A few days before everything was OK, but suddenly, like out of nowhere, above happened.
- Please note that **downloading a key from a keyserver** or any similar insecure activity is not an answer, it **is the problem** itself.
- So a proper acceptable answer **must include a way to (cryptographically) verify that it is legit** and that the originator of the failing (and then fixed) repositories indeed is Canonical and not somebody else who is able to act as a fake Ubuntu mirror, keyserver or MitM (possibly with a legit SSL certificate from some compromized CA).
- It must be able to reproduce the solution on an unmodified, authentic and offlined Ubuntu 20.04 LTS which only has access to some local unverified Ubuntu mirror (so it must verify the authenticity of the mirror, too).
- The solution must not include time distortion (the machine must be NTP synchronized) nor switching off some security features on a global scale (like disabling apt checking for expired keys).
- However the solution can include local modifications which allow to continue to use the expired key, as long as this does not affect any other key on the machine, like manually extending the lifetime of key `C8CAB6595FDFF622`, but only of this lonely key.

### Further notes

```
# apt-get install ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring is already the newest version (2020.02.11.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
# dpkg -L ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring 
/.
/etc
/etc/apt
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2016-dbgsym.gpg
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring
/usr/share/doc/ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring/copyright
/usr/share/keyrings
/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring.gpg
/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-dbgsym-removed-keys.gpg
```

(WTF why `/.`?!?)

```
# apt-key list C8CAB6595FDFF622
pub   rsa4096 2016-03-21 [SC] [expired: 2021-03-20]
      F2ED C64D C5AE E1F6 B9C6  21F0 C8CA B659 5FDF F622
uid           [ expired] Ubuntu Debug Symbol Archive Automatic Signing Key (2016) <ubuntu-archive@lists.ubuntu.com>
```

`expired` explains why `apt` moans.  But knowing this does not give me a solution and just raises questions.

### YMMV

This problem probably will vanish itself as soon as Canonical releases an update to `ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring`.  But until then, as long as this is missing, there must be some way how to properly deal with such a problem yourself using some fallback method, right?  As expired key material is a common problem, not to say one of the most common standard problems in Cryptography, right?

So **it is not Canonical's fault that the key expired**.  Tempus fugit and everybody dealing with Cryptographic Standards knows this.  As this is a standard problem when dealing with Crypto, handling of this situation certainly must be part of each Crypto Standard, right?  So each proper implementation of Crypto must provide some easy way to work around such basic standard problems, by providing a local temporary solution which dissolves automatically when it is no more needed, right?

DES was invented 1975, now it's 2021 already.  Hence Cryptography certainly is mature and does not lack basic standard patterns like dealing with expired keys, right?  And it is simply just my own fault not knowing about how to properly handle such a standard problem, right?  Or am I getting something completely wrong here?

(Disclaimer: Everything in this question is honest with no irony included.  All irony is out there.)

Comment: "there must be some way how to properly deal with such a problem yourself using some fallback method" Why *must* there be such a way? Also: If you want to stay secure like your notes indicate, the solution is pretty much to wait until Canonical updates the key. You could file a bug report too.

Comment: Turns out somebody reported the bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-keyring/+bug/1920640 and the updated keyring has been released in the development version, so it'll soon be coming to the current releases soon anyway. You want to try getting the development package from Launchpad and use it in 20.04 instead of waiting?

Comment: @muru Canonical is not the only one using keys.  There is something on this planet called death.  Dead people usually do not update their keys.  Hence "there must be some way how to properly deal with such a problem yourself using some fallback method", else people must never die and people always must update their keys.

Comment: "Dead people cannot update their keys" doesn't imply "Keys of a dead person can never be updated". It is of course possible for many people to hand over passphrases to their successors so that they may do so. But if the person dying didn't do anything to ensure a successor can gain control of their keys (e.g., keep key passphrases with a trusted third party) then their keys are doomed. That is mathematics, also something on this planet.

Comment: @muru And the latter exactly is my question:  **How to securely use such a doomed key?**  We do not need a solution for exceptions like Mathematicians or Technicians, we need a solution for normal people!  **Normal people are the 90% majority we need to design software for!**  Hence not being able to authenticate the latest download due to an expired keys **is the 90% wrong way of handling it**.  *Note:  The currently accepted solution is not satisfactory.  However, as the problem was solved by Canoncical, it now is difficult to find a proper one in this context here.*

Comment: **That is not a problem for you to solve, though.** That's for the people managing the keys. In **a perfect world**, a monitoring system at Canonical would have been configured to raise an alert when a key is close to expiry, and the people supposed to handle it would have updated it well in advance and no one would have ever been troubled. But **this planet is an imperfect world, and sometimes things slip through the cracks**, and ***sometimes*** the 90% are left with problems that they can't securely fix. Who knows how many times you have updated keyring packages without realising it.

Comment: @muru As you say, this planet is imperfect.  **So you have to cope with this by default.** My system has 24 keys (in `/etc/apt` alone, I do not count all those otheres).  If there is only a 1% chance that such a key times out with no fix, you have a failure chance of 21% that you get into trouble.  Think about a Taxi.  Would you enter a Taxi if there is a 21% chance that you will get involved in an Taxi-accident?  **With  GPG keys you take this risk, each day.**  I refuse to accept such a risk, hence I demand **that this is a problem that I can solve!**

Comment: You can demand a lot of things, but **nobody's going to *have to* give you them.**

Comment: @Tino go cool off, rudeness and such will not be tolerated here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to have been fixed - after running `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring` the problem has went away.

Comment: At my side `apt get update && apt-get upgrade` did it, too.  But still I would like to know how to get around this without compromizing overall security or tweaking the time before it is fixed.

Comment: No need to reinstall, nor to upgrade the whole system. Just do `apt install --only-upgrade ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring` (the `--only-upgrade` option makes sure the package that has been there is upgraded, rather than a new package being installed; you can omit it if you want).

Answer (score 5):

The solution offered at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-keyring/+bug/1920640/comments/32 worked for me:

```
sudo apt remove --purge ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring
sudo apt-key del 0xC8CAB6595FDFF622
sudo apt install ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring
```

Comment: **Good catch!**  But this also does NOT work BEFORE it was fixed by Ubuntu.  **I am so tired to wait for vendors** to detect, that a key timed out after a key timed out!  **An expired key is a standard problem and deserves a standard solution** which is **independent of the vendor**!  Something which can be **applied by normal people in a fully sane and secure way** and even in an "offline sense", such that **nothing externally is required**, everything you need for the fix already must be installed on the system, **right a long time before the key times out**.